# Expanding images dynamically in a modal pop-up

Tags: jquery, image, resize, gallery

I'm about to start working on a portfolio page where the gallery consists of four tabs.

In each tab, there will be three portfolio samples.

When clicked upon, I want the image in question to expand in a modal pop-up.

I'd be grateful if anyone could point me in the direction of a jQuery plugin that could handle this dynamically, i.e. the image on the gallery is the same one that is expanded.

That's all and many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest and best one that I've used. All you need to do is wrap your image in a link element and use a jQuery selector to fire the plugin.

http://fancybox.net/

Comment: This looks very tidy, thanks. Does it expand the thumbnail (or smaller version that prompts the modal expansion)?

Comment: That's up to you. The href inside the a link is the image that gets loaded on the click, so you could put the same image for both the <a> and the <img> elements, but I would recommend making thumbnails for inside the <img> so your not loading giant images.

Also, please click the check mark to accept this answer. This community works on reputation, you earn it by helping others and it gets taken away by posting stupid things!

Comment: That's great, cheers for the tip and you've earned your tick!